Why is this line of code crashing my app?
 nbmWebRTCPeer.generateOffer("local",true)

I'm following the documentations of Kurento WebRTC Peer for Android but i'm not able to generate the sdpOffer as the above said method is making my app crash.
private fun receiveVideo(userId: Any?, userName: String) {
        runOnUiThread {
            val localView :SurfaceViewRenderer = binding.localview
            localView.init(EglBase.create().eglBaseContext,null)

            val mediaConfiguration = NBMMediaConfiguration()
            nbmWebRTCPeer  = NBMWebRTCPeer(mediaConfiguration,this, localView, object:NBMWebRTCPeerObserver(){
                override fun onInitialize() {
                    super.onInitialize()
                    Log.d(TAG,"onInitialize")
                    try{
                        nbmWebRTCPeer.generateOffer("local",true)
                    }catch (e:Exception){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                }

                override fun onLocalSdpOfferGenerated(
                    localSdpOffer: SessionDescription?,
                    connection: NBMPeerConnection?
                ) {
                    super.onLocalSdpOfferGenerated(localSdpOffer, connection)
                    Log.d(TAG,"${localSdpOffer?.description}")
                    if(!isMyVideoPublished){
                        val message = Message(
                            event = "receiveVideoFrom",
                            userid = userId,
                            userName = userName,
                            sdpOffer = localSdpOffer
                        )
                        socketManager.emitMessage(message)
                        isMyVideoPublished = true
                    }
                }

            })

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                nbmWebRTCPeer.initialize()
            }
        }
    }

Or maybe I'm not properly initializing the nbmWebRTCPeer?


whats the error on the log cat?

Well it says Error calling on fill request
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

I've edited the post with the error, so can you please look at it and tell me what's the issue here?@Jayanth

Please include the entire stack trace. But use text, not a picture of the text.

Why is this code wrapped in runOnUiThread? Since Honeycomb onward, you can't execute network-related code on the UI thread. That includes internet sockets.
